# VM crash - can it be related to SSL errors?

Tags: nginx, debian, ssl, attacks

I am not much into server configuration, and I need some help with a problem I am facing.

I have an Debian 11 machine with nginx 1.18.0.

It frequently crashes around 2:00 - 3:00 am.

By inspecting nginx logs I see that at this time there are some errors about handshake:

```
7164 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:141CF06C:SSL routines:tls_parse_ctos_key_share:bad key share) while SSL handshaking, client: 165.154.175.34, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2023/11/03 01:33:43 [crit] 661#661: *7715 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:141CF06C:SSL routines:tls_parse_ctos_key_share:bad key share) while SSL handshaking, client: 106.3.146.202, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2023/11/03 08:11:43 [crit] 664#664: *821 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:141CF06C:SSL routines:tls_parse_ctos_key_share:bad key share) while SSL handshaking, client: 198.199.101.70, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2023/11/03 09:08:37 [crit] 664#664: *1134 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:141CF06C:SSL routines:tls_parse_ctos_key_share:bad key share) while SSL handshaking, client: 64.62.197.231, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2023/11/03 12:57:37 [crit] 664#664: *2438 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:141CF06C:SSL routines:tls_parse_ctos_key_share:bad key share) while SSL handshaking, client: 183.136.225.48, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2023/11/03 13:52:56 [crit] 664#664: *2791 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:141CF06C:SSL routines:tls_parse_ctos_key_share:bad key share) while SSL handshaking, client: , server: 0.0.0.0:443
2023/11/03 13:57:21 [crit] 664#664: *2832 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:141CF06C:SSL routines:tls_parse_ctos_key_share:bad key share) while SSL handshaking, client: 107.178.236.4, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2023/11/03 14:58:28 [crit] 664#664: *3240 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:141CF06C:SSL routines:tls_parse_ctos_key_share:bad key share) while SSL handshaking, client: 138.197.194.139, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2023/11/03 17:27:56 [crit] 664#664: *4361 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:14201044:SSL routines:tls_choose_sigalg:internal error) while SSL handshaking, client: 64.41.200.105, server: 0.0.0.0:443
```

Could this be some kind of attack and if yes how can I defend it?

Is it something relevant?

Should I look somewhere else to find the reason my VM crashes?

Comment: I've fixed the title from claiming that the SSL errors __cause__ the VM crash to asking if it can be __related__.

Comment: `Should I look somewhere else to find the reason my VM crashes?` https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139071/what-are-the-files-located-in-var-crash

Comment: Do you have latest updates installed on the server?

Comment: Thanks for your help and tips. @Greg Askew your link was very informative. It turns out that the problem was an extension on my cms. It's been a week now since I remove it and my has't crash yet.

Answer (score 2):

These are common SSL errors which happen from time to time - bad client, probing, interrupted connections ... Nothing really to worry about. These are not a sign of resource shortage at the server or any other problems and are also not an obvious sign of an attack. These errors are also extremely rare. Therefore it is very unlikely that these errors cause the VM crash or are even related to the VM crash.

Comment: Thank you @steffen-ullrich but should not I do something about these? Or better is there something I can take care so these things are not a problem?

Comment: @Christoforos: The only problem these things are currently causing is some wasted CPU and a log message. You could prevent this by not allowing any connections from outside - but this is likely not what you want. You can also prevent this by having a TLS terminating load balancer or reverse proxy in front of your machine - in which case the problem don't vanish but simply happen at this load balancer.

Comment: Thanks @steffen-ullrich for tour time. Can you point me to some resource for TLS terminating load balance? Thanks anyway though

Comment: @Christoforos: https://www.google.com/search?q=tls+terminating+load+balancer. Basically any layer 7 load balancer for HTTP(S) will do this. haproxy,  load balancers provided by cloud providers ... . But again, this does not "solve" the problem, it just moves it to some other system dealing with it